# how to create a customise menu in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento and I just want to show some menu items and its products on hover but won't be able to find such option. I just added some category and product to it but unable to set on hover. I was trying to locate here I found some code that is being called with some method for core library. I know this is a most common question but wont be able to search solution. hoping that anybody can help me in finding solution.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders a bit unnecessary John mate.

Comment: I'll be the judge of that.